# How to find PE Section and IL Code inside an EXE?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, frameworks, clr

As i searched in google there is a tool called ILDASM to find IL Code.But i want more information on following.

1)  Which is IL Code?

2)  Which is PE Header?

3)  How CLR Makes IL and PE to Native code?.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer on 1 and 2, and for more deep info about the PE header and the CLR loader, read the posts series of Simon Cooper in simple-talk.com. The series called "anatomy of a net assembly" and he explain very well where in the PE specified that it .net assembly and where all the clr staff and metadata exist.

3) About IL, there is a Just In Time (JIT) compiler that takes each method in time and compile it to native code.

And I don't understand your last point about makes the PE native. The PE is Portable Executable file in Windows OS that is not just for .net assemblies. In case of .net it contains sections of bytes that relevant to CLR.